# apply list of function to an iterable one after another in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, functional-programming, reduce

I have a function `process` which takes in a list of functions and an iterable. I want to apply that every function in that list to the iterable one after another. I wrote this which works fine but...

```
def process(list_of_funcs, string):
  for func in list_of_funcs:
    string = ''.join(list(map(func, string)))
  return string

ans = process([lambda c: c.upper(), lambda c: c + '0'], "abcd")
print(ans) # A0B0C0D0
```

I want to skip the for loop (and do it the functional programming way). Is there a way for that in python?

Comment: If the first function were `lambda c: c.upper() * 2`, would you want to get `"AA0BB0CC0DD0"` or `"A0A0B0B0C0C0D0D0"`?

Comment: The latter one - `A0A0B0B0C0C0D0D0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) with parameters

1. as `function` : apply the current function on the previous result
2. as `sequence` : the list of functions
3. as `initial` value : the initial string

```
def process(list_of_funcs, string):
    return reduce(lambda res, f: ''.join(map(f, res)), list_of_funcs, string)
```

Note : no need of intermediate `list`, the `join` takes an `iterator`

---

Here is an example with 3 functions and it gives the same ouput as your initial for-loop solution

```
fcts = [lambda c: c.upper(), lambda c: c + '0', lambda c: c * 2]
ans = process(fcts, "abcd")
print(ans)  # AA00BB00CC00DD00
```